# Taking list from another file and using it in mail script

Tags: python-2.7, file

[image]I am creating an email script and i don't want all the emails to be in the main file, it just looks messy. Any way i can put them in another file and import them in so its shorter? This is what i have now:

```
recipients = ('example@gmail.com','example@gmail.com','example@gmail.com')
```

Comment: You can store them as comma separated values in a file. Read them and use it in the program.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Please see the below answer.

Comment: @SilentMonk Hey sorry im new to this and dont know a lot. i have added my code up top. im not sure how to use what you have added below. Thanks

Comment: @can you please add it as a text? Please go through this link before posting new questions - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. A good question will garner more response.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding a variable in another folder and importing it into my main file.